# 1193 error when creating a mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create this procedure but there is an error that I cannot  solved. It gives me

> error 1193 Unknown system variable p_salida.

I have looked at other topics here, but I find nothing that is useful to me.

Thanks!

```
bloque: BEGIN
 -- PK / UK
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR 1062
BEGIN
 ROLLBACK;
SET p_salida=-5;
END;

 -- FK
 DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR 1452
 BEGIN
    ROLLBACK;
    SET p_salida=-6;
 END;

 DECLARE v_Direccion int;
 DECLARE v_CodUsuario int;

 If not EXISTS (SELECT * From usuarios where Nombre = p_nombre and Apellido 
     = p_Apellido and Correo = p_correo and Contrasena=p_contrasena) THEN
    -- SET p_salida = -1;
    LEAVE bloque;
END IF;


 SELECT codDireccion into v_Direccion 
 From direcciones 
 Order by codDireccion 
 DESC LIMIT 1;

 SET v_Direccion = v_Direccion + 1;

SELECT codUsuario into v_CodUsuario 
From usuarios 
Order by codusuario
DESC LIMIT 1;

    SET v_CodUsuario = v_CodUsuario + 1;

  START TRANSACTION;

  INSERT Into direcciones (CodDireccion, CodigoPostal, Domicilio, Localidad, 
                           Provincia)
       VALUES (v_Direccion, p_CodPostal, 
              p_Domicilio,p_Localidad,p_Provincia);

    INSERT into Usuarios (Apellido, CodUsuario, Contrasena, Correo, 
                          Direccion,FechaNacimiento, nombre)
    VALUES (p_Apellido, v_CodUsuario, p_Contrasena, p_Correo, v_Direccion, 
            p_FechaNacimiento,p_nombre);

   COMMIT;
     SET p_salida = 1;

   END bloque
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare your variable before you can use it. Something like this, placed just after your begin statement (or at least some time before you try to use the variable):

```
DECLARE p_salida INT DEFAULT 1;
```

Documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/declare-local-variable.html

Comment: I have declared it in the mysql routine, but I have tried like you and I get the same error

Comment: CREATE PROCEDURE pr_Registrar (in p_CodPostal char(5), in p_Domicilio varchar(100), in p_Localidad varchar(50), 
in p_Provincia varchar(50), in p_apellido varchar(100), in p_Contrasena varchar(150), in p_Correo varchar(150), in p_FechaNacimiento date,
in p_nombre varchar(30), out p_salida int)

Comment: Please update the question itself clearly so we can see the whole code including this variable, so it's clear where it is in relation to the rest of the code. Code in comments is a) out of context and b) not easy to read. Thanks.